# Django URLs: How to handle a parameter

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-urls

In my `url.py` i have the following line:

```
url(r'^mypage/(?P<q_id>\d+)/$', QuizWizard.as_view(generate_form_tuples()), name='nickname'),
```

QuizWizard is a SessionWizardView

generate_form_tuples is a function (defined inside this module, which has an optional parameter):

```
def generate_form_tuples(q_id=1):
...
```

So, when you  get on `mypage/` you will (maby) have a q_id.
How can i get this parameter from the url and pass it to the `generate_form_tuples()` function ?

P.S. I know that if I redirect this to be handled in a view, the parameter will be sent automatically having as name : q_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to redesign it a bit, like this:

```
url(r'^mypage/(?P<q_id>\d+)/$', generate_form_tuples, name='nickname'),

...

def generate_form_tuples(request, q_id=1):
    ...
    return QuizWizard.as_view(...)(request, q_id=q_id)
```

Comment: I get an error: `'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'`.
I guess that's because it expects to return something like render_to_response() or HttpRedirect ... 
Any ideea?

Comment: It worked, thank you. I will accept your answer in a minute :)